# How to display the content from controller on HTML page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to display the content from controller to the HTML but I am getting the data in console and I am not able to show it on the browser.

**My html code**:

```
<ion-list >
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in taskdetails" item="item" class="item-remove-animate  item " class="itembg" on-swipe-right="showcard(item._id)" on-hold=" data.showReorder = !data.showReorder">
      <span class="toptask" ng-hide="task.hide">
     <span style="opacity:0.8"> {{ item.title| limitTo:10 }}<span ng-show="item.title.length> 10"><b> ...</b></span></span>
        <small class="time " style="float:right;">  <i class="button button-icon icon ion-play balanced" ng-class="{ 'ion-pause assertive': !data.paused, 'ion-play balanced': data.paused}" ng-click="play5(item.id)" ></i>
            </small>
        <div style="float:right;margin-right:5px; font-size: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: black;" class="time icon ">
          <i ng-class="{ 'ion-gear-b': data.paused, 'ion-loading-c spin': !data.paused}" class=" icon balanced" ng-click="showcard(item.id)"></i>
        </div>
        </span>
          </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.openTasks = function (impFlag, urgFlag) {
        console.log("important came as: " + impFlag + " , urgent falg came as: " + urgFlag);
        quadrantservice.gettask.get({
            important: impFlag,
            urgent: urgFlag
        }).$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.taskdetails = result;
            console.log('task detailssssssssssssss' + JSON.stringify($scope.taskdetails));
            /*$state.go('listoftask', {
                important: impFlag,
                urgent: urgFlag
            });*/
        });

$state.go('/listostasks');
    }
```

I am getting the data in console but I am not able to display it on 'listoftasks' state.

Answer (score 0):

You need $watch on your data change because intially data is not available so you need to watch the changes and reflect it accordingly.

```
$scope.$watch('taskdetails',function(newVal){
           if(typeof newVal !='undefined'){
             $scope.taskdetails=newVal;
           }
});
```

//Place this in your maincontroller.

Comment: getting same problem cantable to display the content.

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddle for the same ?

Comment: I have a plunker of the similar. It doesn't call a server but instead sets the controllers-variable delayed. This is the same scenario. After your server responds Angular's digest-cycle is all done and thus doesn't bother to update your view. Don't forget the $apply() to provoke a new digest-cycle. http://plnkr.co/edit/GeraOWp0LFu4XR7Xc0h0?p=preview
Hope this helps :-)